# Cron Statement for the following requirement

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement like below,

The service should run at regular intervals by default one time every 5 minutes. The service should only do this check weekdays (Monday-Friday) between 07:00-17:00.

I have the cron like below to run the service MON-Friday;

```
0 0 7 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

Which will run MON-FRIDAY At 7:00. But how will i make it between 7:00 to 17:00 and which will run every 5 mins?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two lines if you want it to run for the last time at 17:00 and not at 17:05, 17:10, 17:15 etc:

```
0 */5 7-16 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
0 0 17 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

If it doesn't have to run at 17:00 (i.e. the end of the range is exclusive) you can omit the second line

Comment: 0 0/5 7-16 ? * MON-FRI * Does the job. Thank You very Much.

Answer (score 3):

I think your corn expression must be:

```
0 0/5 7-17 ? * MON-FRI *
```

For more explanation you can read [the quartz documantation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)

Comment: Thank You. 0 0/5 7-16 ? * MON-FRI *  works! Sadly i can pick only 1 answer as both of the answers are right and spot on.